# Any way to prevent using project name from go.mod file in import path

Tags: go

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "golang/pkg/closure"
    "golang/pkg/player"
    "golang/pkg/slices"
    "golang/pkg/user"
)
```

Above you can see my imports in `main` package. On same level with `main.go` file , I have folder `pkg` , where I hold my packages and file `go.mod`

```
module golang

go 1.18
```

How can make it working same way but without using `golang/` prefix ?

Comment: That how packages are identified. Pick a more meaningful name if the one you chose isn’t to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to remove the module path from an import path.

You can, however, remove the `pkg` folder from your directory structure and import paths.

Comment: For me pkg seems ok , because it is like name of folder where my packages stored, but golang prefix , seems like it doesn't give any information, or it is just for compiler to know that it is my local package ?

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich The compiler uses the module path prefix in an import path to associate packages with modules. This includes the local module.